# List<? extends MyType>

Tags: java, list, generics, bounded-wildcard

I have a Java question about generics. I declared a generic list:

```
List<? extends MyType> listOfMyType;
```

Then in some method I try instantiate and add items to that list:

```
listOfMyType = new ArrayList<MyType>();
listOfMyType.add(myTypeInstance);
```

Where `myTypeInstance` is just an object of type `MyType`; it won't compile. It says:

> The method add(capture#3-of ? extends
>   MyType) in the type List<capture#3-of
>   ? extends MyType> is not applicable
>   for the arguments (MyType)

Any idea?

Comment: If class Bar extends class Foo and class Baz has generic<T> then Baz<Foo> waldo = new Baz<Bar>() will not work because Baz<Bar> is not a subclass of Baz<Foo>, Bar is a subclass of Foo. Sub classing does not apply to generics. ArrayList<Object> flob = new ArrayList<Double>() will not work. Simply put, inheritance does not apply to generics. Since you do List<? extends MyType> you could have List<Some sub type> = new ArrayList<MyType>. Since they aren't the same. no bueno.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You cannot do a "put" with extends . Look at [Generics - Get and Put rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292109/generics-get-and-put-rule).

Comment: As Josh Bloch says: "Remember PECS: Producer Extends, Consumer Super." Since listOfMyType is a consumer (you are adding to it), `super` is valid and `extends` is not.

Comment: Point of pedantry: You can `put` `null` "with extends". Also you can capture the type and "put" references you've previous "got".

Answer (score 28):

Consider:

```
class MySubType extends MyType {
}

List<MySubType> subtypeList = new ArrayList<MySubType>();
List<? extends MyType> list = subtypeList;
list.add(new MyType());
MySubType sub = subtypeList.get(0);
```

`sub` now contains a `MyType` which is very wrong.

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't need to use the wildcard capture syntax in your case, simply declaring

```
List<MyType> listOfMytype;
```

should be enough. If you want to know exactly why, the [Java Generics Tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20060203125557/http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf) has more than you would ever want to know about the esoteric craziness of Java Generics. Page 20 addresses your specific case.

As for why add with the wildcard capture does not work, it is because the compiler can't determine exactly what subclass of MyType the list will be in every case, so the compiler emits an error.

Answer (score 3):

There is a similar thread here:
[How can elements be added to a wildcard generic collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176446/how-can-elements-be-added-to-a-wildcard-generic-collection)

To get an idea of how generics works check out this example:

```
    List<SubFoo> sfoo = new ArrayList<SubFoo>();
    List<Foo> foo;
    List<? extends Foo> tmp;

    tmp = sfoo;
    foo = (List<Foo>) tmp;
```

The thing is, that  wasn't designed for local/member variables, but for function signatures, that's why it's so ass-backwards.

Answer (score 3):

I dont know if this will really help you, but this is something I had to use while calling a generic method of Spring Framework and wanting to return also a generic list:

```
public <T> List<T> findAll(String tableName,Class<?> table) {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM "+ tableName ;
    List<?> entities = getSimpleJdbcTemplate().query(sql,
            ParameterizedBeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(table));
            return (List<T>) entities;
}
```

Seems the parametrization needs you to use the ? sign in the list to receive the results and then cast the list to the expected return type.

Iam still dazzled by generics...

Comment: dont create SQL querys by String concatenation- see SQL injection