# Explanation of the get-put principle

Tags: java, generics

I have read O'Reilly book, in that I came to know this ***get-put principle***.

> - Use an **`extends`** wildcard when you only **get** values out of a structure.
> - Use a **`super`** wildcard when you only **put** values into a structure.
> - And don't use a wildcard when you both want to get and put from/to a structure.

**Exceptions** are:

> - You cannot put anything into a type declared with an **`extends`** wildcard except for the value **`null`**, which belongs to every reference type.
> - You cannot get anything out from a type declared with an **`super`** wildcard except for a value of type **`Object`**, which is a super type of every reference type.

Can anyone help me to explore this rule at depth? If possible, please put them hierarchical manner.

Answer (score 180, accepted):

Consider a bunch of bananas. This is a `Collection<? extends Fruit>` in that it's a collection of a particular kind of fruit - but you don't know (from that declaration) what kind of fruit it's a collection of. You can *get* an item from it and know it will definitely be a fruit, but you can't *add* to it - you might be trying to add an apple to a bunch of bananas, which would definitely be wrong. You *can* add `null` to it, as that will be a valid value for *any* kind of fruit.

Now consider a fruitbowl. This is a `Collection<? super Banana>`, in that it's a collection of some type "greater than" `Banana` (for instance, `Collection<Fruit>` or `Collection<TropicalFruit>`). You can *definitely* add a banana to this, but if you fetch an item from the bowl you don't know what you'll get - it may well *not* be a banana. All you know for sure is that it will be a valid (possibly `null`) `Object` reference.

(In general, for Java generics questions, the [Java Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html) is an excellent resource which contains the answer to almost anything generics-related you're likely to throw at it.)

Comment: but while fetching a fruit from Collection<?extends Fruits>,
you may get any fruit not the banana.
similarly,while putting a fruit to it,u may add any thing which may not belong to banana fruits

Comment: Java will prevent you from adding anything other than null to a `Collection<? extends Fruit>` for exactly that reason, and you'd have to explicitly cast the result of fetching an item, for precisely those reasons.

Comment: @JonSkeet This might be a stupid question, but in what cases is it useful not to have "access" to both add() and get() methods? I mean, to get() some object out of a list, you have to add it first, right? And vica versa, why would you add it if you cannot get it afterwards?

Comment: @Timmos: Just because *something* has to be able to add a value doesn't mean that *all* code needs to be able to. For example, in order to display a list of person names, I may just need a `Collection<? extends Person>` (or more probably just an `Iterable<? extends Person>`, but...). The code *creating* that collection may well need it to be a `Collection<Employee>`, but the *consuming* code doesn't.

Comment: @JonSkeet OK I understand. So it is some kind of protection?

Comment: @Timmos: You'd have to say *exactly* what you meant by "it" in this case... but yes, the rules of Java generics are designed to provide type safety.

Comment: @JonSkeet This doesn't really make sense to me. Why can I do: `MyType myObject (MyType) object;` and even `T t; MyType myObject = (MyType)(Object)t;` but not `MyType myObject = (MyType) t;`

Comment: @PhilipWhitehouse: It's not clear to me what your comment has to do with this answer... perhaps you should ask a new question giving details of your concerns?