# Generic type compatibility error on List<T> with T being an interface

Tags: java

I have this java code:

```
tgia = new ThumbsGalleryAdapter(this, profilePositionsOverlay.items);
```

and I get this error:

> The constructor ThumbsGalleryAdapter(SharePositionMapActivity, List) is undefined
>   SharePositionMapActivity.java
>   /com.shopzeus.android.majorforms.activity.MainActivity/src/com/shopzeus/android/majorforms/activity
>   line 114 Java Problem

Constructor of `ThumbsGalleryAdapter` is:

```
public ThumbsGalleryAdapter(Activity aActivity, List<ThumbsGalleryItem> aItems)
```

Type of `profilePositionsOverlay.items`:

```
List<SharedPositionMapItem>
```

The name `ThumbsGalleryItem` refers to an interface:

```
public interface ThumbsGalleryItem {
    public String getTitle();
    public String getRemotePath();
}
```

Finally, SharedPositionMapItem is a class that implements ThumbsGalleryItem:

```
private static class SharedPositionMapItem extends OverlayItem implements ThumbsGalleryItem
```

The question is, of course: why `List<SharedPositionMapItem>` is not type compatible with `List<ThumbsGalleryItem>`? Because `SharedPositionMapItem implements ThumbsGalleryItem`, I would expect them to be compatible. What is the solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public ThumbsGalleryAdapter(Activity aActivity, List<? extends ThumbsGalleryItem> aItems)
```

For more details see:
http://codeidol.com/java/javagenerics/Subtyping-and-Wildcards/The-Get-and-Put-Principle/
and this
[Explanation of the get-put principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292109/generics-get-and-put-rule)

Answer (score 5):

Generics are `invarant` in nature which means that `List<Integer>` is not subtype of `List<Object>`

what you need is **List of Any kind of ThumbsGalleryItem** which you can declare like below

```
 List<? Extends ThumbsGalleryItem>
```

You can read more about [wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html)