# How to downcast List<A> to List<B> when we know List<A> contains only B

Tags: java, polymorphism

Lets say I know for certain that a list contains only elements of type B which extends A. Here is an example representing my situation:

```
public static class Animal {
    public void feed() {}
}
public static class Cat extends Animal {
}
public static class Zoo {
    public List<Animal> m_animals;
    
    public Zoo() {
        m_animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();
    }
    public void feedAnimals() {
        for(Animal animal : m_animals)
            animal.feed();
    }
}
public static class CatZoo extends Zoo {
    public void addCat(Cat cat) {
        m_animals.add(cat);
    }
    List<Cat> getCats() {
        List<Cat> cats = new ArrayList<Cat>();
        for(Animal cat : m_animals)
            cats.add((Cat) cat);
        return cats;
    }
}
```

I feel like I'm doing something wrong but I can't quite put my finger on it. `CatZoo` is still a `Zoo` and I need the `Zoo` methods. `Cat` is definitely an `Animal` and I need the `Animal` methods. Anybody who deals with `CatZoo` should only deal with `Cat` and not `Animal`. But `getCats()` becomes super inefficient. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't have a `Zoo<A extends Animal>`?

Comment: If we continue with this example there would be too many specific `CatZoo` functions related only to cats, which cannot be put inside a generic `Zoo`.

Comment: I guess this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15427624/could-not-downcast-using-list-class-in-java answers how but I still think my design is somehow wrong.

Comment: Why wouldn't you have `List<A> getAnimals()` on `Zoo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a generic `Zoo`. That way you can move common logic to the base class while letting the subclasses know what type they're working with:

```
public static class Zoo<A extends Animal> {
    public List<A> m_animals;

    public void add(A animal) {
        m_animals.add(animal);
    }
}

public static class CatZoo extends Zoo<Cat> {
    public void meow() {
        for (Cat cat : m_animals)
            cat.meow();
    }
}
```