# Generic wildcard in Java

Tags: java, generics

I'm writing a generic class:

```
public class Node<T> {
    private Node<T> parent = null;
    private List<? extends Node<T>> children = null;

    public Node<T> getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Node<T> parent) {
        if(this.parent != null){
            // Remove current parent's children references
            this.parent.getChildren().remove(this);
        }

        // Add references
        this.parent = parent;
        parent.getChildren().add(this);
    }

    public List<? extends Node<T>> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }
}
```

I want some other class which subclass this Node. This code cannot be compiled with the error on line `parent.getChildren().add(this);`. Because I declared getChildren() with `List<? extends Node<T>>` as return type, and 'this' is type `Node<T>`.

Is there anyway to solve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292109/generics-get-and-put-rule

Answer (score 1):

Declare the list as:

```
List<Node<T>> children
```

You may still put instances of subclasses in the list.

If you leave it as an unknown type, the compiler can't ensure *which* class it is typed as. Eg it might be typed as SubClassA, but you're adding SubClassB and it has no way to know **based on the declared type**, which is all the compiler has to go on. At runtime, while the type of list and child might match, the compiler can't assert.

Comment: Change the declaration of 'children' to List<Node<T>> is a way, but actually I need to run some subclass-specified method on it, like: children.get(0).encode("abcdaaaa"). If I changed the declaration, I have to cast it and I don't think it's a good way. :-)

Comment: I don't think there's a way around casting