# <? extends SuperType> cannot be applied to SuperType

Tags: java, generics

I have a problem with generics.

I have one SuperType and two SubTypes. The class structure is following:

```
class SuperType {}
class FirstSubType extends SuperType {}
class SecondSubType extends SuperType {}
```

Then I create TypedClass with one method:

```
abstract class TypedClass<T extends SuperType> {
    protected abstract String getStatus(T o);
}
```

I try to use it as an anonymous classes: one for FisrtSubType and one for SecondSubType:

```
new TypedClass<FirstSubType>() {
    @Override
    protected String getStatus(FirstSubType o) {
        return "FirstSubType";
    }
};
```

and

```
new TypedClass<SecondSubType>() {
    @Override
    protected String getStatus(SecondSubType o) {
        return "SecondSubType";
    }
};
```

And I try to keep theese objects in variable with type:

```
TypedClass<? extends SuperType> typedClass;
```

When I get an object of SuperType and try to call getStatus with that object as an argument I get an error: ? extends SuperType cannot be applied to SuperType.

The code is following:

```
private void go(SuperType superTypeObj, String strT) {
    TypedClass<? extends SuperType> typedClass = getTypedClass(strT);
    String status = typedClass.getStatus(superTypeObj);
    System.out.println(status);
}
```

The code of above method brokes in second line (calling getStatus with superTypeObj as an argument).

The method `getTypedClass(String strT)` returns `TypedClass<? extends SuperType>` and creates `TypedClass<FirstSubType>` or `TypedClass<SecondSubType>` depending on String parameter (strT):

```
private TypedClass<? extends SuperType> getTypedClass(String strType) {
    TypedClass<? extends SuperType> res = null;
    if ("FirstSubType".equals(strType)) {
        res = new TypedClass<FirstSubType>() {
            @Override
            protected String getStatus(FirstSubType o) {
                return "FirstSubType";
            }
        };
    } else {
        res = new TypedClass<SecondSubType>() {
            @Override
            protected String getStatus(SecondSubType o) {
                return "SecondSubType";
            }
        };
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: You should take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292109/generics-get-and-put-rule

Comment: I closed your question as duplicate but if you think duplicate doesn't explain your problem and you will be able to explain which part it not explained I will reopen your question.

Comment: This from your link was about collections and a rule about puting and geting, but I think it is the same rule in Java, that prevents from sending an object that is super-type to a method argument which is typed by generics with wildcard extends (? extends super-type).