# Cannot return supertype in generic method

Tags: java, generics

Some example code:

```
public class Main {
    class SomeType {

    }
    class A {
        protected <T extends SomeType> T createSomething()
        {
            return null; // Don't worry about this.
        }
    }
    class B extends A {
        @Override
        protected <T extends SomeType> T createSomething()
        {
            SomeType orig = super.createSomething();
            // do some stuff with orig
            return orig;
        }
    }
}
```

What am I getting wrong here?

On the line

`return orig;`

the compiler spits out the error that

`Type mismatch: cannot convert from Main.SomeType to T`

Thanks to `<T extends SomeType>`, we can be sure that `T` is always a subtype of `SomeType`, right? So why can't I just return the supertype `SomeType`?

I've already read [<? extends SuperType> cannot be applied to SuperType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23995682/extends-supertype-cannot-be-applied-to-supertype) and [Explanation of the get-put principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292109/generics-get-and-put-rule) but I don't see how it applies here.

Comment: Did you try casting: `return (T)orig;` ?

Comment: well yeah I know this works as I can be sure `T` is precisely that type. I just wanted to avoid the casting. And for the sake of interest.

Comment: I'm just curious: can original `createSomething()` ever return something else than `null` without casting? AFAIK you don't have any means to create or get an exsiting `T` object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Thanks to `<T extends SomeType>`, we can be sure that `T` is always a subtype of `SomeType`, right?

Right.

> So why can't I just return the supertype `SomeType`?

Because it might not be a `T`!

Put it this way - imagine `SomeType` is `Object`, and `T` is `String`. You're suggesting that this code should work:

```
String foo() {
    return new Object();
}
```

It works the *other* way round - you can return a *subtype* reference for a method declared to return a *supertype*, but that's different.

The fix is easy though - just change `orig` to be of type `T`:

```
T orig = super.createSomething();
```

Then it compiles with no problems.

Comment: Hmm... Okay in this point of view, I agree. But as the class is not typed and there are no other methods, how is `T` going to be determined? By the way: I cannot modify the super class I'm extending, it's in a library.

Comment: @Atmocreations: `T` is going to be determined by the caller. For example: `x.<SomeSubType>createSomething()`. And no, you don't get to find that out at execution time, due to type erasure. Normally you'd have a `Class<T>` parameter as well, if you need to know it.

Comment: @JonSkeet I just have a doubt. Is `protected <T extends SomeType> T createSomething()` converted to `SomeType createSomething()` after compilation? I know type information is used for compilation check only and will not be available at run-time.

Comment: @user3218114: Yes, but the generic part is preserved as metadata.

Comment: Thanks, If yes then why I can't return `SomeType` as return value? If you need then I can ask it in a separate post.

Comment: @user3218114: because the erasure happens *after* the compiler checks that your code is safe. In this case, your original code simply isn't safe.