# Java Why use of bounded wildcards in this example?

Tags: java, generics

I'm taking a practice exam for one of my classes, I came across a problem that asked me to implement a static generic method. I was correct for the body of the method, but my guess for the actual method signature was different.

I guessed:

```
public static <T> boolean isSorted(T[] array, Comparator<T> cmp){ ...
```

The practice exam's answer, however, used a bounded wildcard like this:

```
public static <T> boolean isSorted(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> cmp)
```

I read through the javadoc again and even though I know what this means (`super` being restrictive in a upwardly inclusive manner in the class hierarchy for that type `T` you specify), I don't think I fully understand *why* you would want to use a bounded wildcard in like this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292109/generics-get-and-put-rule. And then learn about PECS (producer extends consumer super).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Java, subclasses ought to behave like base classes and possibly *extend* behavior - using your proposed signature, an array of `Integer` for example could only be checked against a `Comparator` working on `Integer` only and not by a `Comparator` working on `Number`, for example. This lower bound only broadens the possible use cases for the method as it extends the number of possible `Comparator` objects for re-use.

Comment: Another way to say this would be "If I have a comparator able to sort any Number, I certainly should be able to compare Integers, so it should be a valid second argument to isSorted".

Comment: That took me a little while to wrap my head around, but that makes perfect sense. Thanks for clarifying that for me!

Comment: "only and not by a Comparator working on Number" although in this case it would, because an array of Integer *is* an array of Number.