# Inconsistency in Java 8 method signatures

Tags: java, java-8

Java 8 has given us new methods with really long signatures like this:

```
static <T,K,U,M extends Map<K,U>> Collector<T,?,M> toMap(
    Function<? super T,? extends K> keyMapper, 
    Function<? super T,? extends U> valueMapper, 
    BinaryOperator<U> mergeFunction, Supplier<M> mapSupplier)
```

What I find odd about this is that wildcards have been used to ensure that the first two parameters are as general as possible, yet the third parameter is just a `BinaryOperator<U>`. If they'd been consistent, surely it would be a `BiFunction<? super U,? super U,? extends U>`?. Am I missing something? Is there a good reason for this, or did they just want to avoid making an already horrendous signature even worse?

**Edit**

I understand PECS, and I understand the principle that `mergeFunction` should be thought of as a way of taking two `U`s and getting back a `U`. However it would be useful to be able to have an object that could be reused in many different ways. For example:

```
static final BiFunction<Number, Number, Double> 
        MULTIPLY_DOUBLES = (a, b) -> a.doubleValue() * b.doubleValue();
```

Obviously this is not a `BinaryOperator<Double>`, but it could be *treated* as one. It would be great if you could use `MULTIPLY_DOUBLES` as *both* a `BiFunction<Number, Number, Double>` and a `BinaryOperator<Double>`, depending on the context. In particular, you could simply pass `MULTIPLY_DOUBLES` to indicate that you want a load of `double`s to be reduced using multiplication. However the signature for `toMap` (and other new methods in Java 8) does not allow for this kind of flexibility.

Comment: `? extends U` is not equivalent to just `U`.

Comment: @GriffeyDog I know that. I think what I've written would be a more general signature, not an equivalent one.

Comment: @pbabcdefp the _principle_ of an `*Operator` is to operate on the same input and output arguments; as such `super`ing arguments and `extends`ing return values would make no sense.

Comment: And suddenly Java closures just got a lot less appealing to me.

Comment: @robbmj with type inference and IDEs you don't notice.  It's not too bad

Comment: @dkatzel If I were to write a library that accepts closures, would this signature be typical?

Comment: @robbmj no, this method is one of the more complicated ones

Comment: "to avoid making an already horrendous signature even worse" seems like a good guess.  Sure, some flexibility was sacrificed, but (relative) simplicity of the API may have been deemed more valuable.

Comment: No, you've got the explanation right.  This would work if it was the broader `BiFunction`, but they did want to minimize the signature complexity -- and more importantly, a narrower signature makes it easier for type inference to work, so you can just pass in an untyped lambda and have it inferred correctly.

Comment: @fge I've edited the question to show the kind of thing I'd like to be able to do. I get your point, but I think it makes the API less flexible.

Comment: Ironically, [`Map.merge`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) where `mergeFunction` will end up *does* accept a `BiFunction<? super V,? super V,? extends V>`.

Comment: @Holger thanks for that. Interesting. That shows it wasn't a stupid question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right in that the functional signature of the *merge* operation (the same applies to *reduce*) does not require an interface like `BinaryOperator`.

This can not only be illustrated by the fact that the `mergeFunction` of the `toMap` collector will end up at [`Map.merge`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) which accepts a `BiFunction<? super V,? super V,? extends V>`; you can also convert such a `BiFunction` to the required `BinaryOperator`:

```
BiFunction<Number, Number, Double> 
    MULTIPLY_DOUBLES = (a, b) -> a.doubleValue() * b.doubleValue();
Stream<Double> s = Stream.of(42.0, 0.815);
Optional<Double> n=s.reduce(MULTIPLY_DOUBLES::apply);
```

or full generic:

```
public static <T> Optional<T> reduce(
    Stream<T> s, BiFunction<? super T, ? super T, ? extends T> f) {
    return s.reduce(f::apply);
}
```

---

The most likely reason for creating `BinaryOperator` and `UnaryOperator` is to have symmetry with the primitive type versions of these functions which don’t have such a super interface.

In this regard, the methods *are* consistent

- `Stream.reduce(BinaryOperator<T>)`
- `IntStream.reduce(IntBinaryOperator)`
- `DoubleStream.reduce(DoubleBinaryOperator)`
- `LongStream.reduce(LongBinaryOperator)`

or

- `Arrays.parallelPrefix(T[] array, BinaryOperator<T> op)`
- `Arrays.parallelPrefix(int[] array, IntBinaryOperator op)`
- `Arrays.parallelPrefix(double[] array, DoubleBinaryOperator op)`
- `Arrays.parallelPrefix(long[] array, LongBinaryOperator op)`

Answer (score 3):

the `BinaryOperator<U> mergeFunction`  needs to take `U`s from an input source and put them into another consumer.

Due to the Get and Put Principle, the type has to be exactly the same.  No wild cards.

> The get-put principle, as stated in [Naftalin and Wadler's fine book on generics, Java Generics and Collections](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596527754.do) says:
>
> Use an extends wildcard when you only get values out of a structure, use a super wildcard when you only put values into a structure, and don't use a wildcard when you do both.

Therefore it can't be`BiFunction<? super U,? super U,? extends U> mergefunction` because we are doing `get` and `put` operations.  Therefore the input and result type must be identical.

see these other links for more about Get and Put:

[Explanation of the get-put principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292109/generics-get-and-put-rule) (SO question)

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp07018/

**EDIT**

As Gab points out, the Get and Put principle is also known by the Acronym PECS for "Producer Extends Consumer Super"

[What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs)

Comment: @Gab Thanks!  Forgot about that acronym.  Updated answer

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the implementation of the [Collectors#toMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) in question, one can see that the operator is passed through to some other methods, but eventually only arrives as the `remappingFunction` in various forms of [`Map#merge(K key, V value, BiFunction<? super V,? super V,? extends V> remappingFunction)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-).

So using `BiFunction<? super V, ? super V, ? extends V>` instead of `BinaryOperator<V>` would indeed work here, without causing any problem. But not only here: The [`BinaryOperator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BinaryOperator.html) is only a specialization of [`BiFunction`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiFunction.html) for the case that the operands and the result are all of the same type. So there are **many** places where one could allow passing in a `BiFunction<? super V, ? super V, ? extends V>` instead of a `BinaryOperator<V>` (or, more obviously: One could **always** use a `BiFunction<V, V, V>` instead...)

---

So up to this point, there seems to be no *technical* reason why they chose to only support a `BinaryOperator<U>`.

There was already speculation about possible *non-technical* reasons. For example, limiting the complexity of the method signature. I'm not sure whether this applies here, but it could, indeed, be a trade-off between the complexity of the method and the intended application cases: The concept of a "binary operator" is easily comprehensible, for example, by drawing analogies to a simple *addition* or the union of two sets - or *maps*, in this case.

A possible not-so-obvious technical reason could be that there should be the possibility to provide implementations of this method that internally would *not* be able to cope with the `BiFunction`. But considering that the `BinaryOperator` is only a specialization, it's hard to imagine what such an implementation should look like.

Comment: @Holger what obsolete additional interface are you referring to? `BinaryOperator`?

Comment: @pbabcdefp: Yes, if every use of a `BinaryOperator<X>` was instead using `BiFunction<X,X,X>` or `BiFunction<? super X,? super X,? extends X>`, there was no need for that `interface`.

Comment: @Holger Same with `UnaryOperator`. Those 2 additional interfaces actually reduce flexibility

Comment: @Holger. Symmetry with primitive versions is the most convincing explanation I've seen for this. If you make it an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @pbabcdefp I also considered something like the "symmetry", but mainly referring to other operations that might build upon (or be simplified versions of) the `toMap` function. But interestingly, the symmetry argument does *not* hold for the particular `toMap` method...

Comment: @Marco13 You're right there isn't a primitive version of `toMap`. But the "symmetry" argument (I agree it's not the right word) is a plausible explanation of why they decided in general to use `UnaryOperator<U>` and `BinaryOperator<U>` rather than `Function<? super U,? extends U>` and `BiFunction<? super U,? super U,? extends U>`. I upvoted your answer and accepted Holger's, but it was pretty arbitrary.

Comment: @pbabcdefp I did not want to argue or bargain here ;-) Strictly speaking, **ALL** functional interfaces could have been offered as a single interface: `Function<A,B>`. That's it (with `A` being something like a `Tuple`, for `Bi`- and higher arity functions). But the designers made some reasonable decisions about which functions should be offered in a "fixed" form (like `BinaryOperator`), and for which functions a dedicated, primitive version should exist. It probably was not easy, and some people might complain e.g. about missing `Float`-primitive versions etc., but that's a different story...

Comment: @Marco13 That's true, although personally I'm glad Java doesn't have `Pair` or `Tuple`. I think it's fair to say that if there was `IntUnaryOperator` but not `UnaryOperator` there would be people on here asking why that is (probably me!).