# Use of Unaryoperator and Binaryoperator when I have Function in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8

In Java 8, there are many functional interfaces provided such as UnaryOperator, BinaryOperator and Function etc.

The Code,

```
UnaryOperator<Integer> uOp = (Integer i) -> i * 10;
BinaryOperator<Integer> bOp = (Integer i1, Integer i2) -> i1 * i2 * 10;
```

can always be written using Function as below,

```
Function<Integer, Integer> f1 = (Integer i) -> i * 10;
BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> f2 = (Integer i1, Integer i2) -> i1 * i2 * 10;
```

So, whats the use of these operator interfaces ? 
Are they achieving anything different than what can be achieved using Function ?

Comment: Closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29242311/2711488

Answer (score 4):

They are here for your convenience. You can spare writing `BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer>` and just write/use a `BinaryOperator<Integer>` instead. An additional benefit: you can ensure that the function that is given to you accepts 1 or two parameters of the same type and return exactly that type without much more writing.

Additionally due to the nature of `BinaryOperator<T>` it makes more sense to put something like [`minBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/BinaryOperator.html#minBy(java.util.Comparator)) and [`maxBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/BinaryOperator.html#maxBy(java.util.Comparator)) there, which doesn't really make so much sense to put into a `BiFunction<T, U, R>`. As the given parameters there are of same type and the return type is ensured also to be the same, a comparator can be easily applied... very convenient.

Comment: Since `minBy` and `maxBy` are `static` methods *returning* a `BinaryOperator<T>`, they would simply return a `BiFunction<T,T,T>`, without loosing any functionality.

Comment: true... the convenience (simplicity and certainty) that these are guaranteed to be the same types is probably the more important point.

Answer (score 4):

Functional interfaces should be specialised as possible.

Having

```
Function<Integer, Integer> f1 = (Integer i) -> i * 10;
```

Instead of:

```
UnaryOperator<Integer> uop1 = (Integer i) -> i * 10;
```

is actually a code smell (there is also Sonar Rule `squid:S4276` for this).

The simple reason for this is that these interfaces were created to avoid passing unnecessary type parameters `n` times while you have only one.

```
public interface UnaryOperator<T> extends Function<T, T>
```

So writing a `Function<T, T>` is just longer and unnecessary.

Talking about other interfaces like: `IntConsumer` vs. `Consumer<Integer>` or `DoubleToIntFunction` vs. `Function<Double, Integer>` where the second option may lead to unnecessary auto-boxing and may downgrade performance.

So that's why using more specific and appropriate interface makes your code look cleaner and keeps you away from surprises.

Comment: Most of the time, you will provide a lambda expression where a function is expected, without ever writing down the interface type. The fact that Sonar calls it a code smell, doesn’t say anything, if the `UnaryOperator` did not exist, Sonar did not call using `Function<X,X>` a code smell.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they're functionally identical. They even extend the classes you're talking about and use the same [SAM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17913409/what-is-a-sam-type-in-java). The `UnaryOperator` and `BinaryOperator` interfaces only define static methods.

```
public interface UnaryOperator<T> extends Function<T, T>

public interface BinaryOperator<T> extends BiFunction<T,T,T>
```

They're simply there for brevity. Why specify a type parameter 2 or 3 times when you can do it once?

Answer (score 0):

`UnaryOperator` and `BinaryOperator` are shortcuts for `Function` and `BiFunction` when the type of return type is the same as the input type. I think that they also may carry different meannings, an operation and a function may have different intrepretations depending on your context this is essentially for code readablity and not for technical reasons.