# How do I make a list of several kind of object if I cannot use wildcards?

Tags: java, bounded-wildcard, generics

I want to make a `List` which can hold two kind of `Object`. What comes in my mind is to use wildcard. Below is my code.

```
public class Parent {
  //code  
}

public class ChildOne extends Parent {
  //code
}

public class ChildTwo extends Parent {
  //code
}

public class Implementation {

  List<? extends Parent> list;

  public Implementation() {

    list.add(new ChildOne());
    list.add(new ChildTwo());

    ChildOne co = list.get(0);
    ChildTwo ct = list.get(1);

  }

}
```

I cannot use `<? extends Parent>`,  since I do `add`.

But, I cannot use `<? super Parent>` either, since I do `get`.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292109/generics-get-and-put-rule) stated: `don't use a wildcard when you both get and put.`.

So, how do I do to make a list of several kind of Object without using wildcards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wild cards is not appropriate for this use case. You should simply do

```
List<Parent> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

and cast the return value from `get`:

```
ChildOne co = (ChildOne) list.get(0);
ChildTwo ct = (ChildTwo) list.get(1);
```

Comment: knowing the solution is so damn simple, I feel kind of silly thinking I need wildcard for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 2):

You can just create your list this way:

```
List<Parent> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new ChildOne());
list.add(new ChildTwo());
```

Now you can add and get any object that is (or extends) `Parent`.

Take in mind that you need to cast the object to the proper one when you get it.

```
ChildOne co = (ChildOne) list.get(0);
ChildTwo ct = (ChildTwo) list.get(1);
```