# Parameter extending appropriate parameter in Java

Tags: java

Let's say I have class `Animal` and class `Bear` which extends class `Animal`.
Now in constructor I have parameter with `Animal`:

```
public class Forest {

   private List<Animal> animals;

   public Forest(List<Animal> list) {
      animals = list;
   }
}
```

Why I cannot do something like that?

```
List<Bear> bears = new ArrayList<>();
new Forest(bears);
```

I thought that `Bear` is in detail case `Animal`. 
Can I fix this only by adding template to `Forest<P extends Animal>` ?

Answer (score 5):

You can use a wild card

```
  private List<? extends Animal> animals;

   public Forest(List<? extends Animal> list) {
      animals = list;
   }
```

This lets the list contain any kind of animals, even a mix of different types.

This will all compile:

```
       List<Bear> bears = new ArrayList<>();
       new Forest(bears);

       ...

       List<Animal> mix = new ArrayList<>();
       mix.add(new Animal());
       mix.add(new Bear());

       new Forest(mix);
```

The downside is you won't know the type except that they are animals.

There are rules for if and when you can use wildcards and when to use `extends` vs `super` depending on if you are putting new elements or not from the Collection.

See the [Explanation of the get-put principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292109/explanation-of-the-get-put-principle)  which is sometimes called PECS which stands for "Put Extends, Create Super"

**EDIT**

To be able to add other animals to the list later, you have to change the animal list field to not use a wild card.  However, the constructor can still use the wild card but you should probably create a new List object passing in the list from the constructor.

This will work:

```
private List<Animal> animals;

   public Forest(Collection<? extends Animal> list) {
      animals = new ArrayList<>(list);
   }


   public void add(Animal a){
       animals.add(a);
   }

   public void addAll(Collection<? extends Animal> as){
       animals.addAll(as);
   }
```

then later

```
 List<Bear> bears = new ArrayList<>();
 Forest forest = new Forest(bears);

 forest.add(new Animal());
```

I also added an `addAll` method which also uses a wildcard

```
 //same mix and bears lists from before
 Forest forest2 = new Forest(mix);
 forest2.addAll(bears);
```

Comment: great answer :) one question, in the moment you initialize `new Forest(bear)` you can after add other kind of animals in this forest??

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this method

```
public static <C,T extends C> List<C> convert(List<T> list) {
        List<C> c = new ArrayList<>(list.size());
        c.addAll(list);
        return c;
}

new Forest(convert(bears));
```