# Java Generics - can I get rid of the raw type in this use case

Tags: java, generics, raw-types

I'm working with the following jaxb class hierarchy:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(...)
public class RecordModifyType extends RecordBaseType
{
    ...
    public List<FieldModifyType> getField() { ... }
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(...)
public class RecordAddType extends RecordBaseType
{
    ...
    public List<FieldAddType> getField() { ... }
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(...)
public class FieldModifyType extends FieldBaseType
{
    ...
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(...)
public class FieldAddType extends FieldBaseType
{
    ...
}
```

I stumbled upon a method in some other class with the following signature (**please note the raw types**):

```
private void createFields(FTPPartner user, 
                          String addressMasterDataID, 
                          String connectionMasterDataID, 
                          CRTypeEnum crType, 
                          List addrFields, 
                          List connFields)
```

This method is called from different parts of the class sometimes with  `List<FieldAddType>` as arguments and other times with `List<FieldModifyType>`.

Now I'm trying to get rid of the raw types in its signature.

Following the [get-put principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292109/explanation-of-the-get-put-principle), I decided to change the signature to

```
 private void createFields(FTPPartner user, 
                              String addressMasterDataID, 
                              String connectionMasterDataID, 
                              CRTypeEnum crType, 
                              List<? super FieldBaseType> addrFields, 
                              List<? super FieldBaseType> connFields)
 {
     ...
     FieldBaseType someField = new buildField(...);
     addrFields.add(someField);
     ...
 }
```

... since the createFields implementation is **only putting** stuff in these collections.
The problem is that since RecordModifyType#getFields() returns `List<FieldModifyType>` and RecordAddType#getFields() returns `List<FieldAddType>`,
I now can not invoke the method, since it only allows for super types of FieldBaseType, not subtypes:

```
RecordAddType addrRecord = getRecordAddType(...);
RecordAddType connRecord = getRecordAddType(...);
List<FieldAddType> addrFields = addrRecord.getFields();
List<FieldAddType> connFields = connRecord.getFields();
createFields(user, 
             addressMasterDataID,
             connectionMasterDataID,
             crType
             addFields, // This won't compile
             connFields); // This won't compile
marshalRecord(addrRecord);
marshalRecord(connRecord);
```

Using raw types is working as expected - there are no compile errors and marshalling works.

So my question is - is there a way to preserve the behaviour but get rid of the raw types?

Comment: You may want to create a small and complete example that reproduces the problem. It is unclear what the link is between the createFields method and the getField methods...

Comment: The problem is the api, you cannot properly use a `List<FieldModifyType>` where you put in a `FieldBaseType` using rawtypes, it will `ClassCastException`s when you retrieve it in the other class. The other solution would be creating a new arraylist to hold the `FieldBaseType` from the list returned by `getFields()`

Comment: How would `createFields()` decide whether to add `FieldAddType` or `FieldModifyType` instances?

Comment: I'm not sure why you have that class hierarchy but it indicates that new records would be of type `RecordAddType` and _only_ have fields of type `FieldAddType` while already existing records would be of type `RecordModifyType` and can have _both_ field types. If that's the case then to me `createFields()` looks like it should only accept `List<FieldAddType>` since you'd not _create_ modified fields.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, the compiler is complaining because it doesn't know that the type `? super FieldBaseType` for the call is the *the same* type for each parameter. Also, because both concrete types are subclasses of `FieldBaseType`, that's how the type needs to be bound IMHO.

Try typing the method:

```
private <T extends FieldBaseType> void createFields(FTPPartner user, 
                          String addressMasterDataID, 
                          String connectionMasterDataID, 
                          CRTypeEnum crType, 
                          List<T> addrFields, 
                          List<T> connFields) {
    // during the call, the compiler knows that addrFields and connFields
    // hold the same type as each other
}
```

Now the type is inferred at the call point.