# Generics Upper Bound Wild Card gives compilation error

Tags: java, generics

I was trying some sample programs on Generics Upper/Lower bounds..  Generics Upper Bound is giving compilation error...But Lower Bound is fine.
I am just trying to put a List of type T into a set and try both Upper and Lower bound scenarios..

Please help to identify the issue with testUpperBound(T t) method and why exactly does the testLowerBound(T t) method compile and the testUpperBound(T t) one doesn't. I checked other similar threads..But still I haven't got it clear.

Please Let me know if need more details .

```
 public class TestGenerics<T> 
    {

        public static void main(String...args)
        {
           List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
           list.add("New ArrayList");
           new TestGenerics<List<String>>().testUpperBound(list);
           new TestGenerics<List<String>>().testLowerBound(list);

        }

       public  void testLowerBound(T t)
       {
            Set<? super ArrayList<T>> lowerBoundSet = new HashSet<>();
            lowerBoundSet = new HashSet<List<T>>();
            ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add(t);
            lowerBoundSet.add(list);  // compiles..

            out.println(lowerBoundSet);
        }

        public  void testUpperBound(T t)
        {
            Set<? extends List<T>> upperBoundSet = new HashSet<>();
            upperBoundSet = new HashSet<List<T>>();
            ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add(t);
            upperBoundSet.add(list);  // Doesn't compile..

            out.println(upperBoundSet);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have your answer :

[Explanation of the get-put principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292109/explanation-of-the-get-put-principle)

It is java rule, that's all.
I may give you an example with your code why it would be unsafe if compilation passed  :

```
public void extendsExample(){
  Set<? extends List<? extends String>> setOfList = new HashSet<>();
  Set<ArrayList<String>> setOfArrayList = new HashSet<>();

  // now setOfList var refers to a set 
  // which contains a arraylist of String
  setOfList = setOfArrayList;

  // compilation fails
  setOfList.add(new LinkedList<String>());
 }
```

Imagine the compilation doesn't fail. 
It means `setOfArrayList` instance which is a set which should contain `ArrayList` instances, contains now a list of `LinkedList` element.

If you iterate on `setOfArrayList` you will not have exclusively `ArrayList<String>` elements as expected. It's no safe and that's why the compilation fails.

Here the example with `<? super` :

```
public void superExample(){
  Set<? super ArrayList<String>> setOfArrayList = new HashSet<>();

  // compilation ok
  setOfArrayList.add(new ArrayList<String>());
  // new anonymous type derivating from ArrayList
  ArrayList<String> derivedArrayList = new ArrayList<String>(){
  };
  // compilation ok
  setOfArrayList.add(derivedArrayList);
}
```

Comment: Awesome :) ..Finally I got it clear....  Thanks David..! . Appreciated and Accepted the Answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can not modify a collection parameterized with `<? extends SomeType>`. Java just does not allow that as it is not safe action. add() modifies the collection, so you can't do it. There is no such restriction for `<? super SomeType>`

Comment: Thanks for answering Yaroslav... But could you please help to find what exactly is the difference between lower and upper methods in my code where lower one compiles and upper one doesn't ?

Comment: Uh not quite, you cannot _insert_ into a `Collection<? extends T>` but you can insert into a `Collection<? super T>`, and vice-versa (can retrieve from `<? extends T>` and cannot retrieve from a `<? super T>`). Iirc you can still retrieve from a `<? super T>` with casting but in general it's an extension of PECS

Comment: As for the reason behind the restriction... It relates to type erasure. Java doesn't know the exact parametrization in runtime so modification is potentionally dangerous operation for upper bounded collections. There is a lot of examples of what could go wrong if there were no such restriction in the Internet.

Comment: Thanks for your patience friends.. :) .  Still can we have one example here.. ?  :) . I have "Effective Java" with me ...But still somehow not getting the answer for this 100% clear..  :(

Comment: The duplicate target already has examples, please check them out.

Comment: Thank You All for explaining.  I got it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, we do not know at compile time what type of lists are contained in the `upperBoundSet`.  It could be a `Set<ArrayList<T>>`, or it could be a `Set<LinkedList<T>>`, or it could be one of many other alternatives.

If it turns out to be a `Set<LinkedList<T>>`, then adding an `ArrayList` to it is obviously a bad idea.  But because we don't know what type the set's contents are, it takes the safer option and blocks it.