# <? super E> and <? extends E> for List

Tags: java, generics

Having the following simple class structure:

```
class A {
}

class B extends A {
}

class C extends B {
}
```

I'm creating an ArrayList to keep objects of the earlier created classes:

```
List<? extends A> list1 = new ArrayList<A>();
List<? extends B> list2 = new ArrayList<B>();
List<? extends C> list3 = new ArrayList<C>();

List<? super A> list4 = new ArrayList<A>();
List<? super B> list5 = new ArrayList<B>();
List<? super C> list6 = new ArrayList<C>();
```

To each of those lists I'm trying to add 1 object of each earlier created class: A,B,C. The only possible combination is:

- adding object of class A,B,C to list4
- adding object of class B and C to list5
- adding object of class C to list list6. 
  The rest of the tries gives compiler errors, such us:

> The method add(capture#1-of ? extends
>   A) in the type List is not applicable for the
>   arguments (A)

Why can't I add any object of class A,B,C to list1/2/3?
Why e.g. list4 accepts objects of classes A,B,C if they are supposed to be a super class of class A, as the list4 is defined?

Comment: I think this question has the answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918026/list-extends-mytype

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"? extends A" means "some type derived from A (or A itself)". So for instance, a `List<ByteArrayOutputStream>` is compatible with `List<? extends OutputStream>` - but you shouldn't be able to add a `FileOutputStream` to such a list - it's meant to be a `List<ByteArrayOutputStream>`! All you know is that anything you fetch *from* the list will be an `OutputStream` of some kind.

"? super A" means "some type which is a superclass of A (or A itself)". So for instance, a `List<OutputStream>` is compatible with `List<? super ByteArrayOutputStream>`. You can definitely add a `ByteArrayOutputStream` to such a list - but if you fetch an item from the list, you can't really guarantee much about it.

See [Angelika Langer's Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#WIldcard+Instantiations) for much more information.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good way of understanding! There's still one thing that's weird for me - I've found out that you can make a list:

List<? extends B> list2_2 = new ArrayList<A>();

instead of:

 List<? extends B> list2 = newArrayList<B>();

and still add object of class B.

Answer (score 4):

The type definition  `List<? extends A>` is not usable for a *mutable* List - the explanation given in Java generics [Java Generics Pdf](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf) is

> The add() method takes arguments of type E, the element type of the
>   collection.
>       When the actual type parameter is ?, it stands for some unknown type.
>   Any parameter
>       we pass to add would have to be a subtype of this unknown type. Since we
>   don’t know
>       what type that is, we cannot pass anything in.

However, when the typedef is `List<? super A>` then the type parameter ? is implicitly typed.

Answer (score 2):

```
List<? extends A> list1
```

It is a list, whose type element could be any unknown subclass of A. For example, it could be a D subclass. Therefore, you can't add anything to it, it could be wrong...

```
List<? super A> list4
```

It is a list, whose type element could be A, or a superclass of A (does not exist in that case, except Object). Therefore, you can add A objects to it, or any subclass of A such as B or C.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work that way.

You should use `<? extends T>` when you create function which argument is collection of unknown subtype of some type, and you want to fetch objects from that collection:

```
int sum(Collection<? extends Integer> collection) {
    for (Integer : collection) {
        // do sth
    }
    // ...
}
```

You cannot add new items to this collection, because you don't know which concrete type is this collection holding. All you know is that that type extends `Integer`.

You use `<? super T>` when you want to add new items of type `T` to collection and return that collection, but then you cannot guarantee what you can retrieve from it and you have to cast result of `get()` or check its type. You can safely add items of type `T` and subtypes, and retrieve items of type `T`.

Comment: use Number, Integer is final :)

Answer (score 0):

`List<? super B>` allows you to use Lists of any supertype of B, i.e. list5 = new ArrayList<**A**>();
or list5 = new ArrayList<**Object**>();

You can safely add B (and subtypes) to every list that use supertypes of B, but you can not add any supertype of B. Imagine this:

```
public void myAdd(List<? super B> lst) {
  lst.add(new Object()) //this is a supertype of B (compile time error)
}
...
ArrayList<A> list = new ArrayList<A>();
myAdd(list); //tries to add Object to a list of type A
```