# Generics, setting ArrayList<? extends Option> to ArrayList<OptionChild>

Tags: java, generics

I have this pseudo code :

```
Example A
Interface Option
Class OptionImplementer implements Option
ArrayList<ArrayList<? extends Option>> test = new ArrayList<ArrayList<OptionImplementer>>(); <-- Fails?
```

Why does it fail? Child does implement Option, and I've also tried Super keyword instead of extends.

As "bonus" question, these constructor signatures are postulated to have same erasure:

```
 Example B
    public void test(ArrayList<ArrayList<? extends Option>> test) {

}
public void test(ArrayList<ArrayList<OptionImplementer>> test) {

}
```

Example A or B should work. A fails so be B should work...

Comment: It does not fail. Maybe you should post the exact code with the exact compiler error you are getting.

Comment: It's not clear what the bonus question actually is.

Comment: Sorry, why does B example fail when A example also fails?  *A* gives this error: 'Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<ArrayList<OptionImplementer>> to ArrayList<ArrayList<? extends Option>>'  *B* gives 'Method test(ArrayList<ArrayList<? extends Option>>) has the same erasure test(ArrayList<E>) as another method in type Test'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because a

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<? extends Option>>
```

can contain both entries of type `ArrayList<Option>` and `ArrayList<OptionImplementer>` although

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<OptionImplementer>>()
```

can only contain entries of the second type. In the first case, the following is allowed:

```
test.add(new ArrayList<Option>());
test.add(new ArrayList<OptionImplementer>());
```

Concerning your second question, it is unrelated but it just means that if you remove all generic info, the methods would have the same signature, which is not allowed.

Comment: :( so theres no way to do something like this: 'ArrayList<ArrayList<? extends Option>> test = new ArrayList<ArrayList<OptionImplementer>>();'

Comment: Not without tricking the compiler because this "cast" would allow you to corrupt your `ArrayList<ArrayList<OptionImplementer>>` with `ArrayList<Option>` entries. However you could go through a crappy unchecked cast like this: `ArrayList<ArrayList<? extends Option>> test = (ArrayList<ArrayList<? extends Option>>) (Object) new ArrayList<ArrayList<OptionImplementer>>();`

Comment: Thanks, I figured it would be something like that :(

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure it fails? It shouldn't, and it doesn't when I try this:

```
interface Option {}
class Child implements Option {}

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<? extends Option> list = new ArrayList<Child>();
    }
}
```

Note, however, that you cannot add anything to `list` if you write it like this. Why you can't add to such a list has been asked many times before, see for example:

- [<? super E> and <? extends E> for List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906677/super-e-and-extends-e-for-list)
- [what is the difference between 'super' and 'extends' in Java Generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910892/what-is-the-difference-between-super-and-extends-in-java-generics)
- [What is a difference between <? super E> and <? extends E>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368166/what-is-a-difference-between-super-e-and-extends-e)
- [Difference between <? super T> and <? extends T> in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java)

Comment: I've updated the code to reflect the correct scenario, sorry.