# What is meaning of <E extends Number> List<? super E> return type of method in java

Tags: java, generics, collections, return-type

I was reading OCJP questions and i found one question in that following method signature was given.

```
public static <E extends Number> List<? super E> process(List<E> nums)
```

I would like to know what actually is Return type or what is mean of `<E extends Number> List<? super E>` written as return type.

> Let me give whole question.

Given a method declared as:

```
public static <E extends Number> List<? super E> process(List<E> nums)
```

A programmer wants to use this method like this:

// INSERT DECLARATIONS HERE

```
output = process(input);
```

Which pairs of declarations could be placed at

// INSERT DECLARATIONS HERE

to allow
the code to compile? (Choose all that apply.)

A.

```
ArrayList<Integer> input = null;
ArrayList<Integer> output = null;
```

B.

```
ArrayList<Integer> input = null;
List<Integer> output = null;
```

C.

```
ArrayList<Integer> input = null;
List<Number> output = null;
```

D.

```
List<Number> input = null;
ArrayList<Integer> output = null;
```

E.

```
List<Number> input = null;
List<Number> output = null;
```

F.

```
List<Integer> input = null;
List<Integer> output = null;
```

G. None of the above.

Answer:

B, E,
and
F
are correct

Comment: See answers to [<? super E> and <? extends E> for List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906677/super-e-and-extends-e-for-list) post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this generic method the return type is determined by the argument type. The argument can be `List<Number>` and List of subtypes of Number. Eg if you call process with this arg

```
List<Integer> list = ...
process(list)
```

the return type will be `List<? super Integer>`. Generic type with `? super` can be assigned only to generic type with `? super`

```
List<Integer> input = null;
List<? super Integer> output = process(input);
```

it cannot be `List<Number>` or `List<Object>` because they allow writing subclasses of generic parameter. Eg `List<Number> list` allows `list.add(1L);`

Correct answer is G.

Comment: R u sure G is correct answer? i dont think so

Comment: Then try to compile B

Comment: u r right.Means official book for OCJP also can have misteks :O

Comment: Explanation is given by them is, The return type of process is definitely declared as a
List
, not an
ArrayList
, so
A
and
D
are wrong.
C
is wrong because the return type evaluates to
List<Integer>
, and that can't
be assigned to a variable of type
List<Number>
. Of course all these would probably cause a
NullPointerException
since the variables are still null—but the question only asked us
to get the code to compile