# why is this assignment not allowed in Java generic

Tags: java, generics

here is the code example

```java
public static ArrayList<? extends A> get(){
   return null;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
   ArrayList<A> test=get();//not allowed
}
```

since `A` certainly is the super class of any `? extends A`, why is the code snippet not allowed?

Comment: You've got it the wrong way round; `ArrayList<A>` is assignable to `ArrayList<? extends A>`, but you're trying to assign an `ArrayList<? extends A>` to `ArrayList<A>`. Imagine if the code is like `String s = new Object();`, which isn't allowed despite the fact that `String` satisfies `Object`.

Comment: Also your `main` is not written correctly, you did not include `String [] args`.

Comment: @kaya3 I think my code is like `Object s=new String()` , since `Object` satisfy `? extends Object`

Comment: But it is not like you think, your code is like `String s = new Object();`. Because `ArrayList<? extends A>` is a supertype of `ArrayList<A>`.

Comment: In test you could insert an `A` but the original list could actually be a `ArrayList<AChild>`

Comment: You should probably just use an interface.

Comment: @kaya3 supertype? afaik, only array type in java is covariant

Comment: @JoopEggen but you couldn't put an `A` into ArrayList<Achild> (? extends A) either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906677/super-e-and-extends-e-for-list

Comment: The original list can be a `List<X>` with an (unknown) X that extends A. Hence an error as you would not like someone inserting a non-X object into the list. _That is all, and make a `List<?>` result practically useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got it the wrong way round; `ArrayList<A>` is assignable to `ArrayList<? extends A>`, but you're trying to assign an `ArrayList<? extends A>` to `ArrayList<A>`.

In fact, `List<? extends A>` is a supertype of `List<A>`, not a subtype; using the REPL:

```java
> List<A> list = new ArrayList<? extends A>();
Error:
unexpected type
  required: class or interface without bounds
  found:    ? extends A

> List<? extends A> list = new ArrayList<A>();
[]
```

So your code is like `String s = new Object();`, not like `Object s = new String();`.

---

OK, so why isn't `List<? extends A>` assignable to `List<A>`? The answer is in the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). A `List<A>` can do some things that a `List<? extends A>` can't do, such as `.add(new A())`:

```java
> List<A> listA = new ArrayList<>();
[]

> listA.add(new A());
true

> List<? extends A> listExtendsA = new ArrayList<B>(); // B is a subclass of A
[]

> listExtendsA.add(new A());
Error:
incompatible types: A cannot be converted to capture#2 of ? extends A
```

This makes sense because you *shouldn't* be allowed to add an instance of `A` to a `List<B>`. On the other hand, `List<A>` is assignable to `List<? extends A>`, because a `List<A>` can do everything that a `List<? extends A>` can do.

Actually, a `List<? extends A>` can't do very much; you can't even `.add(new B())`, for example.

Comment: why is ` List<? extends A> list = new ArrayList<A>();` allowed ? since you couldn't put `A` into the list.

Comment: You can't call `.length()` on an `Object`, either, but that doesn't mean `String` should not be assignable to `Object`; it means the opposite, `Object` should not be assignable to `String`.