# generics ? extends T - can't use T

Tags: java, generics

I have a case where I pass a param of type `Queue<? extends StringReference>` into a method and try to add to that queue a `new StringReference(pointer)` and get in eclipse a

```
The method add(capture#3-of ? extends StringReference) in the type Queue<capture#3-of ? extends StringReference> is not applicable for the arguments (StringReference)
```

Even if I try it with `? extends Object` I get the error?

The problem ist that the client calls this method with a `Queue<StringUse>` which is a subclass of `StringReference`.

Where is my thinking barrier?

cheers 
Markus

Comment: Read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918026/list-extends-mytype?rq=1 and  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcardGuidelines.html

Comment: @ZouZou that was the thing I was looking for thx!

Comment: @ZouZou:  I was looking for that duplicate.  Good find.