# Does this make a difference in using generics?

Tags: java, generics

Are they exactly the same or used for different situations?

```
public List<? extends Object> do(){
   return ...
}
```

VS

```
public List<Object> do(){
  return...
}
```

Comment: The former may return a list of some subclass of Object. The latter returns a list of objects of arbitrary classes. See also ["List<? extends MyType>"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918026/list-extends-mytype).

Comment: Generics is tough. The PECS question should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Those are not the same.

A `List<? extends Object>` may be a list of any type.

Since you don't know what type the list actually contains, you can't put anything into it.

Comment: Since everything is implicitly a subclass of Object, why aren't they the same? I mean in both cases, the do() can return a list of "everything". Isn't right?

Comment: @user697911 Try both with `do().add(new Object())`.

Comment: No.  `List<? extends Object>` means you _don't know_ what type the list is supposed to have; just that whatever type it is extends `Object`.  It might actually be a `List<Cat>`, so you can't put in a `Dog`.

Comment: The wildcard `extends` syntax says that the list contains references all of the same type, which type is a subtype of the upper bound, `Object`. Without the wildcard, `List<Object>`, it's a list of references all of the named generic element type, `Object`, but each element can be of a different subtype of the named type.