# Why doesn't List<? extends A> accept an implementation of B which extends A?

Tags: java, generics

Why doesn't this work? I thought the list would be able to accept any object that is an instance of `A`.

```
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    interface A {}

    interface B extends A {}

    class BImpl implements B {}

    List<? extends A> listOfAExtensions;

    void function() {
        B b = new BImpl();
        listOfAExtensions.add(b);
        // error
        // The method add(capture#1-of ? extends Test.A)
        // in the type List<capture#1-of ? extends Test.A>
        // is not applicable for the arguments (Test.B)
    }
}
```

Comment: Also see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918026/list-extends-mytype

Answer (score 1):

```
List<? extends A> listOfAExtensions
```

is not the same as

```
List<A> listOfAExtensions
```

because you can assign

```
List<? extends A> listOfAExtensions = new ArrayList<CImpl>();
```

where `CImpl` is an implementation of `A` unrelated to `BImpl`. If you could add a `BImpl` to `listOfExtensions` after that, you would be adding a `BImpl`
to a list of unrelated `CImpl`, which would not make sense. Therefore the compiler doesn't allow you to add instances of `BImpl` to `listOfAExtensions`.