# Fundamentals on Generics

Tags: java, generics

Why does the following does not work?

```
Vector<? extends SomeClass> v = new Vector<SomeClass>();  
SomeClass e = new SomeClass();  
v.add(e);
```

I get a compilation error that:

> The method add(capture#1-of ? extends SomeClass) in the type
>   Vector is not applicable for the
>   arguments (SomeClass)

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176446/how-can-elements-be-added-to-a-wildcard-generic-collection?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem basically is that by declaring `v` as `Vector<? extends SomeClass>` you say that it's a collection of `SomeClass` *or* one of its *subclasses*. The compiler cannot make any assumptions about what specific type the container actually hold, even if the assignment to `new Vector<SomeClass>()` is done on the same line. As much as the compiler knows `v` might  have been created as `new Vector<SubClassOfSomeClass>()`. That is why it refuses to **put** `SomeClass` instances (or anything else for that matter) to the collection. You can however **get** the `SomeClass` elements out of it.

If you want to be able to **put** elements to the collection, then declare `v` as `Vector<? super SomeClass>`, by which you say that it's a container of `SomeClass` *or* one of its *superclasses*. The compiler knows then that a `SomeClass` instance will certainly fit in such a collection.
You cannot however **get** a `SomeClass` element out of that collection, as the compiler knows nothing about the type of elements in it (except that it is some superclass of `SomeClass`). By the definition of `v` it might as well be just a collection of `Object`s.

This is called the **put/get principle** in short which is discussed in detail also in other posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1292109/1276804).

Answer (score 4):

Collections with [generic wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html) which extend from a type do not allow you to add to that `Collection`.

As the compiler does not know exactly what *type* of `SomeClass` you are attempting to add, it doesn't allow it. The exception to this is a `null` object which can represent any type of `Object`.

To answer your comment: Although you cannot *add* to the `Collection`, it cannot be described as *read only* as it is still possible to *remove* `Objects`.

To allow addition of `Objects`, you would need to use a known type:

```
Vector<SomeClass> v = new Vector<SomeClass>();
```

Comment: @Jim you still can remove by index from "wildcared" vector.

Comment: Using `Vector<? super SomeClass>` does allow you to add to a collection.

Answer (score 1):

This is explained [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html). The list declared like that is effectively a read-only list, but it is more flexible than a normal `List<AbstractClass>` list.

If you want to use an abstract class as a template, just use it straight on like this: `List<SomeClass> list`.

Consider reading [Java language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html), there is a lot of information about the generics logic.

Answer (score -1):

There should not be problem to you in your problem explanation.  I understood your problem as in the following code.

```
import java.util.*;
class Test
{
  int x;
}
public class Demo
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      Vector<Test> vect = new Vector<Test>();

      Test t1 = new Test();
      Test t2 = new Test();
      t1.x = 10;
      t2.x = 20;

      vect.add(t1);
      vect.add(t2);

      for(Test t : vect)
      {
         System.out.println(t.x);
      }  
  }
}
```

I read this type of gimmicks in [Vector Play With](http://way2java.com/collections/vector-play-with/).

Comment: OP didn't ask for beginner training on vector operations. Your post is definitely not an answer to OP's question. And posting irrelevant answers is not the best way to promote your blog.