# incompatiable types error when returning generics wildcard collection

Tags: java, android, generics

I'm working on a function that generates a two-level associative array fetched from the database. The array will be used to create an expandable list view. It needs to be a generics wild card `List` because the expandable list adapter requires that.

I just read from [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176446/how-can-elements-be-added-to-a-wildcard-generic-collection) that in order to add elements to a generics collection, `super` or `extend` has to be employed with the generics. It works okay, however, why am I getting an incompatiable types error when returning the collection?

```
public HashMap<String, List<? super SearchField>> getAll() {

    HashMap<String, List<SearchField>> listCollection = new HashMap<String,List<SearchField>>();

    /************DataBase Query***************/    
    try {

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

            List rowList = new ArrayList<SearchField>();

            do {

                SearchField sf = new SearchField();

                sf.value = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("value"));

                sf.group_title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("group_title"));

                sf.key = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("key"))

                rowList.add(sf);

                Map<String,String> group = (Map<String,String>)listCollection.get(sf.group_title);

                if(group == null){

                    listCollection.put(sf.group_title,rowList);

                }else{

                    listCollection.get(sf.group_title).add(sf);

                }


            } while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
    return listCollection;
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

SearchField Class

```
public class SearchField {

    public String value;

    public String key;

    public String group_title;


}
```

I followed this example from the other thread:

```
  public List<? extends Foo> getFoos()
  {
    List<Foo> foos = new ArrayList<Foo>(); /* Or List<SubFoo> */
    foos.add(new SubFoo());
    return foos;
  }
```

The two-level array I'm trying to create from the fetched result is like this in PHP:

```
$group = array("A Group"=>array("value"=>2,"title"=>"Apple"),
               "B Group"=>array("value"=>1,"title"=>"Boy")
         )
```

Update:

The reason I want to return the wildcard because my expandable list adapter is used across different activities and takes collections of different structures.

```
public ExpandableListAdapter(FragmentActivity context, List<String> group,
        Map<String, List<?>> listCollection) {
    this.dataCollections = listCollection;
}
```

So I'd like to return a list using wild card for the adapter.

Comment: You have to provide the part of your code where you call the getAll() method.

Comment: Can you just change `getAll` declaration so it returns `Map<String, List<SearchField>>`? Honestly, the wildcard seems pointless. By the way, `catch (Exception e) {}`, oof. Never, ever, ever do this. At the very least put `e.printStackTrace();` so you at least *know* if an exception is thrown. (And why are you catching and eating *all* exceptions? There's no reason to do that. Always catch the most-specific exception you possibly can.)

Comment: You have to provide the part of your code where you call the getAll() method.

Comment: `(Map<String,String>)listCollection.get(sf.group_title)` This is what I'm talking about. Note that the values in `listCollection` are *declared to be* `List` so you are apparently casting `List` to `Map` here. This will throw a `ClassCastException`, which your empty catch block is eating.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the way you are defining rowList. Try this:

```
List<SearchField> rowList = new ArrayList<SearchField>();
```

instead of

```
List rowList = new ArrayList<SearchField>();
```

Comment: You are correct that [raw types should not be used](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it), but this won't cause a compilation error.

Comment: You are right that should not result in compilation error atleast. Can you try HashMap<String, List<? super SearchField>> listCollection = new HashMap<String,List<? super SearchField>>(); instead of HashMap<String, List<SearchField>> listCollection = new HashMap<String,List<SearchField>>();

Comment: That would solve the compilation error but I don't think it will make their code work, per my other comments. ;) I'm also not even sure that they need the wildcard in the first place. Doesn't stop you from putting it in your answer, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using `List<? extends SearchField>` in the function declaration?

Comment: This won't solve the compilation error, and it changes the meaning of the code. See [PECS](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2723397/2891664).