# How to mock findByPrincipalName in spring\mockito

Tags: spring, spring-security, mockito

I am trying to mock `findByPrincipalName` as in my test context I do not have redis set up but I am unable to do so, I get the following error:

```
The method thenReturn(Map<String,capture#2-of ?>) in the type OngoingStubbing<Map<String,capture#2-of ?>> is not applicable for the arguments (Map<String,capture#3-of ? extends Session>)
```

I do not really understand what this error is telling me, below is how I am attempting to mock the method:

```
Map<String, ? extends Session> sessions = new HashMap<>();

@MockBean
private FindByIndexNameSessionRepository<?> sessionRepository;

when(this.sessionRepository.findByPrincipalName(VALID_SUB)).thenReturn(sessions);
```

What do I need to do to be able to mock this method? The class `RedisSession` is not accessible so I cannot create an instance of this to use.

Comment: What is `VALID_SUB`?

Comment: Its a string value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a problem related to mocking, but simply a generic type mismatch. You defined the repository as `FindByIndexNameSessionRepository<?>`, while your `sessions` reference type is `Map<String, ? extends Session>`, so your repository returns `?` (2), while you're trying to return an object containing `? extends Session` (3). The numbering in the last sentence marks the bounds (`?`) accordingly to the log you've provided - bounds defined in different places are treated as different type definitions and do not match (read more [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html)).

What you need to do is: define types for both the repository and the object it should return so that they match. One way of doing that would be simply sticking to the interface (`Session`) or if you wanted to make it more concrete, you could use a generic type definition on the class level (`<T extends Session>`) and apply it to the repository and the map.

```java
@MockBean
private FindByIndexNameSessionRepository<Session> sessionRepository;

@Test
void test() {
    Map<String, Session> sessions = new HashMap<>();
    when(sessionRepository.findByPrincipalName(VALID_SUB))
            .thenReturn(sessions);
    ...
}
```

```java
class TypedIndexNameSessionTest<T extends Session> {

    @MockBean
    private FindByIndexNameSessionRepository<T> sessionRepository;

    @Test
    void emptySessions() {
        Map<String, T> sessions = new HashMap<>();
        when(sessionRepository.findByPrincipalName(VALID_SUB))
                .thenReturn(sessions);
        ...
    }
}
```

---

I've tested the code locally and pushed it to [my GitHub repository](https://github.com/Jonarzz/stack-overflow/tree/73651394/spring-boot-module/src/test/java/io/github/jonarzz) - you can see the full example there (all tests pass).

Comment: Well this certainly fixes the issue, if I make the repository type `<? extends Session>` and I make the sessions map type `<String, ? extends Session>` I am still unable to put a `MapSession` into the sessions map, even though it does extend `Session`, is this related to the same issue?

Comment: Why are you using a wildcard there and not just `Session`? `? extends Session` doesn't mean "anything that extends Session", but "a certain (unknown) type that extends Session". See for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/176478/3305737) and [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super).

Comment: I am not using `? extends Session`, just trying to understand why your answer works and why the above doesnt, I used the solution from your answer in my tests.

Comment: `?` means "some type", but it is not specified and if it is defined in multiple places around the class, it is interpreted as different types by the compiler (hence the `2` and `3` markers in the error message). That's why defining `T` on the class level works, because the same type is used explicitly in mutliple places.